# Pass properties or an object instance to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing an Android application and I have a doubt about what to do.

I have an instance of Dog class. This class has two properties `isMale` and `Id` (and another ones).

If I pass these two properties to another `Activity`:

```
public void onAddClick(View view)
{
    if (mSelectedDog == null)
        // TODO: Show a message to indicate that or maybe, the button add could be disabled.
        ;
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddDogActivity.class);

        // Pass to AddDogActivity if we are going to add a male or female dog.
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        // Pass dog's sex.
        b.putBoolean(Constants.ACT_ADD_DOG_IS_A_MALE, mSelectedDog.isMale());
        // Pass dog's id
        b.putInt(Constants.ACT_ADD_DOG_ID, mSelectedDog.getId());
        intent.putExtras(b);
        // TODO: Maybe it is better pass Dog instance instead of isMale and ID.

        startActivity(intent);  
    }
}
```

I will need to instance another `Dog` class object on `AddDogActivity`.

**Which is it better, pass these two properties or pass `mSelectedDog` to `AddDogActivity`?**

Comment: I recommend you make a factory in your new Activity that knows how to create its own intent. It makes it much easier to accommodate future changes. So for example add a method to it such as static Intent createIntent(Context context, int dogId); The coupling here will break in ways that will still compile when the input data needed by the class inevitably changes.

Comment: @metalideath Thanks for your recommendation. Do you have any example about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Dog class implements Serializable and that's it. Then you can do this:

```
intent.putExtra("selected_dog",mSelectedDog);
```

And then you can retrieve in this way, using Fragments:

```
getArguments.getSerializable("selected_dog");
```

For Activity is:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("selected_dog");
```

or:

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selected_dog");
```

Make the "selected_dog" a constant in your app, it would be much easier to remember the key.

VERY IMPORTANT: if your Dog class has another Class for example Person or Owner, then this class needs to implements Serializable as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would say pass `mSelectedDog` - this seems to be proper encapsulation to me. Isn't this ultimately what you want to do? Act on the `Dog` class object in another Activity?

What happens if there were more properties of `Dog` you needed? The solution of passing each property doesn't scale well for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Ken Wolf suggests, I agree that it is a better idea to pass a Dog object rather passing individual properties. I have done it and I have suffered. Imagine in the future you want to pass a few more properties, you would have to make changes to your caller again. And suppose you want to call your AddDogActivity class from multiple points, then you must make sure every point of call is updated.

Major pain. Trust me.

In case you do decide to pass the Dog object, I believe you will have to serialize your Dog class.

Comment: If you want to pass the whole object just make it parcelable. Then you can pass it in the intent. A generator is here devk.it/proj/parcelabler